# как импортировать папку в rust?

Tags: rust

src:

```
folder /
    myfile.rs
main.rs
file.rs
```

file.rs

```
use crate::folder;

fn main() {
    let x = folder::myfile::foo();
}
```

как такое реализовать?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html

Comment: Тут есть ответ на ваш вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519176/how-do-i-use-or-import-a-local-rust-file